# HTML - 2 elements focused at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, tinymce-4

I'm slightly rewriting TinyMCE editor so that it better suited my needs.
One of the changes I want to do is font size input - no select but straight input where you would write any value you want.
I began to experiment with TextBox, but there is a problem.
When I go into that text box, selection from editor is lost, so any change is applied to nothing.
Is there some possibility how to access the text box and not lose the focus in the editor, or some other workaround?

Dialog is not the possibility, as it would completely beat the purpose of simplicity.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect the input to be when typing?

Comment: Without code whe can't help you... But my first tought is to have an onchange on the input field and then update the TinyMCE...

Comment: Input is in editor toolbar.

As to apply changes on change, the problem is that when selection no longer exists, there is nothing to apply changes on.

But below is a good suggestion I am now working on, so there is no need to dig deeper and show code, as it is an application with big dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do as such, but you could maybe re-ceate this functionality with some javascript+css. That may be a bit tricky though, so I would suggest leaving it for later on and go further on actual functionalities of whatever you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and save the selection, and then restore it once the the user completes the input.

```
function saveSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function restoreSelection(range) {
    if (range) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you always save the selection by recalling saveSelection when the selection changes:

```
document.getElementById("editor").onmouseup = function () {
    tinyRange = saveSelection();
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    restoreSelection(tinyRange); 
    document.getElementById("editor").focus();
}
```

check out this jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/5QLDT/

Comment: This seems smart. I'll try to fit it somehow to tinyMCE. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, It might require some ajusting. e.g. what happens when the user selects using the SHIFT + RightArrow. And the thank you is much appreciated, but a vote up will be even more! ;)

Comment: Wanted to, but unfortunately I don't have reputation high enough to do so.